# Half transparent image Pillow

Tags: python, discord, python-imaging-library, nextcord

How do i make an image half transparent like the dank memer command. Ive been using the putalpha since i found it on the Internet when i was searching for a solution but it didnt work. I am using Pillow.

The code:

```
class Image_Manipulation(commands.Cog, name="Image Manipulation"):
    def __init__(self, bot:commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(aliases=["Clown","CLOWN"])
    async def clown(self, ctx, user: nextcord.Member = None):
        if user == None:
            user = ctx.author
        
        clown = Image.open(os.path.join("Modules", "Images", "clown.jpg"))

        useravatar = user.display_avatar.with_size(128)
        avatar_data = BytesIO(await useravatar.read())
        pfp = Image.open(avatar_data)
        pfp = pfp.resize((192,192))
        pfp.putalpha(300)
        if pfp.mode != "RGBA":
            pfp = pfp.convert("RGBA")

        clown.paste(pfp, (0,0))
        clown.save("clown_done.png")

        await ctx.send(file = nextcord.File("clown_done.png"))
        
def setup(bot: commands.Bot):
    bot.add_cog(Image_Manipulation(bot))
```

The dank memer command example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C48zb.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effect you want to achieve is called *average* of two images. [`PIL.Image.blend`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.blend) allow to get *weighted average* of two images. Example usage:

```
from PIL import Image
im1 = Image.open('path/to/image1')
im2 = Image.open('path/to/image2')
im3 = Image.blend(im1, im2, 0.5)
im3.save('path/to/outputimage')
```

where `im1` and `im2` are images of same size (width x height), you might elect to use different 3rd parameter for `Image.blend` if you wish one image to have more impact on result image (`0.0` results in copy of `im1`, `1.0` results in copy of `im2`)

Comment: I see but i got an error ```ValueError: images do not match```. I also converted one of the image to .png but it didn't work, maybe its because discord avatar aren't png so they don't match?

Comment: so i tried saving the avatar into "pfp.png" and created another variable to open the image but the same error popped out again.

Comment: wait nvm i just have to convert them both image to "RGBA" so that they match.

Comment: I got another problem, both image must be 128*128 or they won't work. I want the result of the image blend to be 192*192 so i resized them to 192*192 but it gave me the error `ValueError: images do not match` again.